POWER BI NO ME DIVIDE EL RESULTADO
tengo 2 Medidas las cuales contabilizan mis valores, pero a la hora de dividir esas medidas con una medida de DIVIDE no me da el resultado de esa division (Solo me da 1.00 o 100%).
Asi estan creadas mis medidas:
Medida Efficency:
Efficency = DIVIDE([TotalLinesCompleted],[LinesUser]) 

Medida TotalLinesCompleted:
TotalLinesCompleted = CALCULATE( COUNT(tbl_CombAcarreaDeliv[Item]), tbl_CombAcarreaDeliv[Status] =6 )

Medida LinesUser:
LinesUser = CALCULATE(
        [TotalLinesCompleted],
        tbl_CombAcarreaDeliv[AcarreaID] = VALUES(tbl_CombAcarreaDeliv[AcarreaID])
    )


Quiero pensar que seguramente el SelectedValue es el que esta afectando mi operacion.
